# Database Tables for files in filesystem

Tags: database, database-design

i needed to save images to my back-end, and finally went with storing them in the file system instead of in the database as blobs. So now i have a different issue, i want to make my database as optimized as possible. Here are my needs, and my approaches:

I have these entities:

- User
- Image

In my file system, i can store the images in directories named after the user id. So basically:

- 16

  - asd.jpg
  - blaBla.jpg

Would represent the images about the user with id 16.
Now, i know i will have a lot of directories and a lot of images, and i know that storing their paths in a database would be better than querying the file system. (or would the OS know the locations of all the directories, making these tables not needed?)However i was wondering should i make a table such as `(userId,imagePath)`, connecting every image to a userid, or `(userId,directoryPath)`, connecting every-user with the path to his directory, then use something like `Files.walk(directoryPath)` to list all of the paths of the images inside that directory. What would be a better approach, or is this way to opinion-based ? A completely different approach or any tips would also be appreciated.

Comment: This will depend on what other information you want For example if there is a whole lot of metadata about the image, descriptions, locations, etc, then it makes sense to have the actual files pointed to by the database. If its just a bucket of photos, then maybe not.

Comment: @TomC its pretty much just a bucket a photos. Do i still need to make tables with the file locations, or does the server know the location of every directory and will that be enough.

Comment: This is really just a design question that only you can answer. Personally I would have everything in the database so you can easily do any sort of query against it without having to integrate file system and database code. The only file system code would then be the final read/write of the actual file.